# SpTBX: statusbar: how to get width of last panel

Tags: delphi, sptbxlib

I have `TSpTbxStatusbar`. 10 panels on it (They are `TSpTbxItem`s with fixed or non-fixed width) + splitters. I need to get width of "free space" after last panel. see an image.
How to get it.

[image: statusbar]

I had TBX and used `Status1.Panels[i].Size` to get panel' size. now (sptbx) i can't do it. I haven't `Size` or `Width` prop for `TSpTbxItem`. How to calc width of panels to get result.

Comment: @Ken. added text to asking.

Comment: Do you have an *item* at the specified *free* space?

Comment: In any case, you'll be using *viewers* to locate items. `Status1.View.Find(yourItem).BoundsRect`, you can get a viewer at a particular position: `Status1.Viwer.ViewerFromPoint(..`. If there's no item there, you may have to follow Chris's answer.

Comment: `Status1.View.Find(yourItem).BoundsRect` solved issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's the width of the statusbar, minus the sum of the widths of the prior panels.

Comment: It's much better for all of us if the user learns to try to solve the problem first before just posting here for a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using `View` prop:

```
Status1.ClientWidth - Status1.View.Find(last_status_tbxitem).BoundsRect.Left
```